# Qual a função deste arquivo MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Conforme o projeto abaixo:

http://www.macoratti.net/11/06/pp_mvvm1.htm

Sei que a finalidade da função Main é ser a função principal porém no exemplo apresentado acima o arquivo MainWindow está fazendo também a função de apresentar o layout está função não deveria pertencer ao View? Nesse contexto como eu acrescentaria mais um formulário, de forma aceitável para convenção .NET. Pelo conceito que absorvi foi que deveria acrescentar mais um arquivo estilo MainWindow para acrescentar o layout do segundo formulario que desejo atribuir ao projeto, isto estaria correto. Afinal a função deste arquivo MainWindow apresentar o Layout está correta?

Answer (score 1):

Há uma diferença entre o método `Main` e `MainWindow` do `WPF`, esse `MainWindow` equivale ao `Form1` de uma aplicação `winforms`.

No WPF, você não encontra o método `Main` porque ele é gerado durante a compilação.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2694710/4713574

Comment: Seguindo essa linha de raciocínio o MainWindow equivale ao Form1 de uma aplicação winforms. Então na pasta View entraria apenas o que é equivalente aos controles do winforms?

Comment: pasta View ? pasta você pode criar várias... padronização View, Model e Controller só no MVC, para web.

Comment: Pasta View referente o conceito MVVM aplicado sobre o template WPF.

Comment: entendi, pelo que li aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 sua View então seria as `Window` xaml do wpf, só isso.